# What is the punishment for missing a prayer?

Tags: salat, punishment

In my childhood, I heard stories like if a person misses a prayer, he is punished so and so years in hell fire. In the modern Islam, I do not hear of these.

What is the exact punishment of missing a single prayer? Is there any truth of punishiment of so and so years for missing a prayer?

Answer (score 5):

If you missed a Salat, for a reason, like you slept through it, or you forgot it, or something.  Then you can make it up.  **but**, if someone leaves salat ***altogether***, out of laziness or not wanting to make it, then he/she is a kafir.

The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) [said](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/89):

> العهد الذي بيننا وبينهم الصلاة، فمن تركها فقد كفر
>
> That which differentiates us from the disbelievers and hypocrites is
> our performance of Salat. He who abandons it, becomes a disbeliever

he (peace and blessings be upon him) also [said](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/88):

> ‏إن بين الرجل وبين الشرك والكفر ترك الصلاة‏
>
> Between a man and disbelief and paganism is the abandonment of Salat
> (prayer)

Note: when we talk about abandoning salat altogether, we mean the Fard Salawat.

As for missing one, I am not aware of any punishment, and again there has to be a good excuse, if it was missed on purpose but you still make it up or make the other salat you are not abandoning the salat altogether, and when you abandon it altogether that is when you become a kafir, and Allah knows best.  As for the evidence to support the punishment mentioned in your question, I do not know any authentic Hadith that supports it, but such a hadith may or may not exist.  If you are told this then I suggest you ask for the proof, and it's authenticity.

I am not aware of a hadith which mentions a certain/specific punishment if you miss a salat, I am aware though [of the hadith which says:](https://sunnah.com/nasai/6/19):

> الَّذِي تَفُوتُهُ صَلاَةُ الْعَصْرِ فَكَأَنَّمَا وُتِرَ أَهْلَهُ
> وَمَالَهُ
>
> The one who misses 'Asr prayer, it is as if he has been robbed of his
> family and his wealth

For more information you may listing to [this discussion](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8h-KbnKzCo0) of two scholars.

Comment: thanks for detail answer. I have accepted the answer but I also wanted to know about any particular punishment for missing the salat. If you can add that later, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: @TheTruthSeaker I edited my answer and added what I am aware of, I pray it is of benefit to you.

Answer (score 1):

The one who neglect the prayers will receive Fifteen punishments from Allah. 
Six punishments in this lifetime

Three while dying 
Three in the grave & 
Three on the Day of Judgment.

THE SIX PUNISHMENTS OF LIFE: 
1. Allah takes away blessings from his age (makes his life misfortunate) 
2.Allah does not accept his plea (Dua's) 
3.Allah erases the features of good people from his face. 
4.He will be detested by all creatures on earth. 
5.Allah does not award him for his good deeds. (No thawab) 
6.He will not be included in th! e Dua's of good people.

THE THREE PUNISHMENTS WHILE DYING: 
1. He dies humiliated. 
2. He dies hungry. 
3. He dies thirsty. Even if he drinks the water of all seas he will still be thirsty.

THE THREE PUNISHMENTS IN THE GRAVE: 
1. Allah tightens his grave until his chest ribs come over each other. 
2. Allah pours on him fire with embers. 
3. Allah sets on him a snake called "the brave", "the bold" which hits Him 
from morning until afternoon for leaving Fajr prayer, from the afternoon until Asr for 
leaving Dhuhr prayer and so on. With each strike he sinks 70 yards under the ground.

THE THREE PUNISHMENTS ON THE DAY OF JUDGMENT:

1. Allah sends who would accompany him to hell pulling him on the face.
2. Allah gives him an angry look that makes the flesh of his face fall down.
3. Allah judges him strictly and orders him to be thrown in hell.

Comment: Can you please quote the sources?

Comment: The hadith you are quoting is (mawdu) fabricated